# Want to show integar values as double values while binding gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

the database table Column contains 2397 and 1234.7 but i want to show 2397 as 2397.00 and 1234.7 as 1234.70 in gridview while binding in rowdatabound in vb.net. please help me to fix it thanks in advance

Comment: hi need any clarification to fix this bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the example of formatting numeric value.

```
Dim value As Double

value = 123
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("00000"))
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:00000}", value))
' Displays 00123

 value = 1.2
 Console.Writeline(value.ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
 Console.Writeline(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
              "{0:0.00}", value))
' Displays 1.20

Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("00.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                            "{0:00.00}", value))
' Displays 01.20 

Dim daDK As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK")
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("00.00", daDK))
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(daDK, "{0:00.00}", value))
' Displays 01,20

value = .56
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0.0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                            "{0:0.0}", value))
' Displays 0.6

value = 1234567890
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0,0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))  
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                            "{0:0,0}", value))  
' Displays 1,234,567,890       
Dim elGR As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("el-GR")
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0,0", elGR))
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(elGR, "{0:0,0}", value))    
' Displays 1.234.567.890

value = 1234567890.123456
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0,0.0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))    
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                            "{0:0,0.0}", value))    
' Displays 1,234,567,890.1  

value = 1234.567890
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0,0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))   
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                            "{0:0,0.00}", value))   
' Displays 1,234.57
```

Comment: I'm new to programming i need this in rowdatabound event of gridview in vb.net

Comment: go to gridview property check in event list there is rowdatabound event double click on that it will generate the code. Then get the value from that cell and format that then reassign that to cell.